# Crear un nuevo array a partir de dos array

Tags: php, javascript, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo un array con esta estructura:

http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls

Y tengo este otro array que me da el api de itunes:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack&limit=2

```js
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "kind": "feature-movie",
            "trackId": 735814806,
            "artistName": "Francis Ford Coppola",
            "trackName": "Jack",
            "trackCensoredName": "Jack",
            "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/jack/id735814806?uo=4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Lo que necesito es crear un array con solo una estructura:

```html
{
    "resultados": [
        {
            "nombre": "track",
            "longDescription": "feature-movie",
            "imagen": url,
            "busquedaobtenidade": "itunes"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "track 2",
            "longDescription": "feature-movie 2",
            "imagen": url 2,
            "busquedaobtenidade": "tv maze"
        }
    ]
}
```

Este es el código que llevo hasta el momento, lo único que hago acá es el merge de datos pero no es el resultado que realmente quiero

```html
<?php
   $content=file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack&limit=2");
       $json = json_decode($content, true);
 // print_R($json);
 $count=count($json);


 // for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 // {
 //  echo $json['results'][$i]['trackName'].'<br>';
 //  echo $json['results'][$i]['longDescription'].'<br>';
 // }
?>


<?php
$contenttwo = file_get_contents("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls");
$jsontwo = json_decode($contenttwo, true);

// print_r($jsontwo);


$resultado = array_merge($json, $jsontwo);
print_r($resultado);

// $pila = array();

// array_push($pila, $json, $jsontwo);

// print_r($pila);
?>
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo o existe alguna libreria para hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que estás enfocando mal el problema. Primero imagina que sólo tienes que tratar el json de itunes. Crea un método/función para tratar el json de itunes únicamente. Después imagina que sólo tienes que tratar el json de tvmaze: Crea un método/función para tratar dicho json. Finalmente una vez que tienes los dos resultados de ambos métodos, unirlos debería ser fácil. Puedes crear un tercer método para unir los dos resultados.

Comment: @Julio Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo malo es que no tengo mucha experiencia por lo que no se por donde o como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes traer independientemente los datos de los dos lugares y guardar los resultados en un único `array`, yo en este caso no haría un `array merge` ya que los datos son muy diferentes entre sí. Lo único a tener en cuenta es el formato de los datos obtenidos para recorrererlos, por ejemplo con `foreach`, y obtener los resultados que te interesan en cada caso.

Ejemplo:

```
$a_resultados = array(); $counter = 0;

$content=file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack&limit=2");
$json = json_decode($content);
//print_r($json);

foreach ($json->results as $res) {
    $a_resultados[$counter]["nombre"] = $res->trackName; 
    $a_resultados[$counter]["longDescription"] = $res->longDescription; 
    $a_resultados[$counter]["imagen"] = $res->previewUrl; 
    $a_resultados[$counter]["busquedaobtenidade"] = "itunes"; 
    $counter++;
}


$contenttwo = file_get_contents("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls");
$jsontwo = json_decode($contenttwo,true);

//print_r($jsontwo);

foreach ($jsontwo as $res) {
    $a_resultados[$counter]["nombre"] = $res["show"]["name"]; 
    $a_resultados[$counter]["longDescription"] = $res["show"]["summary"]; 
    $a_resultados[$counter]["imagen"] = $res["show"]["url"]; 
    $a_resultados[$counter]["busquedaobtenidade"] = "tv maze";
    $counter++;
}

print_r($a_resultados);
```

Resultado

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Jack
            [longDescription] => Comedy favorite Robin Williams lights up the screen in JACK, the acclaimed hit that had critics and audiences cheering! Williams stars as a mischievous 10-year-old who acts like any other boy his age, except he's in a grown-up's body. It's nonstop laughs as Jack embarks on the greatest adventure of his young life ... the fifth grade. In his wildest role ever, Williams takes you on a hilarious ride as Jack explores the ups and downs of life from a kid's point of view! With Bill Cosby, and sexy Fran Drescher, Diane Lane, and Jennifer Lopez -- join the millions of moviegoers who loved this outrageous comedy hit!
            [imagen] => https://video-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Video117/v4/f8/5f/77/f85f77f3-746a-0208-c598-d08b05f2d445/mzvf_4681274526170371903.640x476.h264lc.U.p.m4v
            [busquedaobtenidade] => itunes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Jumanji: The Next Level
            [longDescription] => In Jumanji: The Next Level, the gang is back (Dwayne Johnson, Jack Black, Kevin Hart and Karen Gillan) but the game has changed. As they return to Jumanji to rescue one of their own, they discover that nothing is as they expect. The players will have to brave parts unknown and unexplored, from the arid deserts to the snowy mountains, in order to escape the world’s most dangerous game.
            [imagen] => https://video-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Video113/v4/10/c1/51/10c15162-a881-fdf5-149f-850147f526d0/mzvf_10451023053396014921.640x352.h264lc.U.p.m4v
            [busquedaobtenidade] => itunes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Girls
            [longDescription] => 

This Emmy winning series is a comic look at the assorted humiliations and rare triumphs of a group of girls in their 20s.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/139/girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Good Girls
            [longDescription] => 

Good Girls follows three "good girl" suburban wives and mothers who suddenly find themselves in desperate circumstances and decide to stop playing it safe, and risk everything to take their power back.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/23542/good-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Gilmore Girls
            [longDescription] => 

Gilmore Girls is a drama centering around the relationship between a thirtysomething single mother and her teen daughter living in Stars Hollow, Connecticut.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/525/gilmore-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Bomb Girls
            [longDescription] => 

Set in the 1940s, Bomb Girls tells the remarkable stories of the women who risked their lives in a munitions factory building bombs for the Allied forces fighting on the European front. The series delves into the lives of these exceptional women – peers, friends and rivals – who find themselves thrust into new worlds and changed profoundly as they are liberated from their home and social restrictions.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1073/bomb-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Chicken Girls
            [longDescription] => 

Rhyme and her friends — known by their 'ship name, "The Chicken Girls" — have been dancing together forever. But this year, everything's changing...

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/32087/chicken-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Florida Girls
            [longDescription] => 

Florida Girls follows four women who are forced to confront their stagnant lives when their only ambitious friend moves away to follow her dreams. Bound by their friendship, they will attempt to navigate life's curveballs while living below the poverty line.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/42726/florida-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Derry Girls
            [longDescription] => 

16-year-old Erin Quinn lives with her uncompromising mother, her long-suffering father and the fearsome ‘Granda Joe', a man whose love for his daughters and granddaughters is surpassed only by his contempt for his son-in-law.

It's the early 90s, and Erin is used to seeing her country on the nightly news and speaking in acronyms (The IRA, The UDA, The RUC). This is a time of armed police in armoured Land Rovers and British Army check points. But it's also the time of Murder She Wrote, The Cranberries, MJ and Lisa Marie, Doc Martens, bomber jackets, The X Files, Nirvana and Wayne's World. And while The Troubles may hang over her home town, Erin has troubles of her own

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/33320/derry-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => The Powerpuff Girls
            [longDescription] => 

The city of Townsville may be a beautiful, bustling metropolis, but don't be fooled! There's evil afoot! And only three things can keep the bad guys at bay: Blossom, Bubbles and Buttercup, three super-powered little girls, known to their fans (and villains everywhere) as The Powerpuff Girls. Juggling school, bedtimes, and beating up giant monsters may be daunting, but together the Powerpuff Girls are up to the task. Battling a who's who of evil, they show what it really means to "fight like a girl."

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/6771/the-powerpuff-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Brown Girls
            [longDescription] => 

Brown Girls centers on the relationship between Rimmi, an Indian-American aspiring beauty vlogger, and Devi, a young woman who has recently emigrated from India. Brought together by family, Rimmi and Devi instantly clash over their different views on modern life and love while slowly realizing they both have something to learn from one another.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/22131/brown-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => The Golden Girls
            [longDescription] => 

The Golden Girls follows four South Florida seniors sharing a house, their dreams, and a whole lot of cheesecake. Bright, promiscuous, clueless, and hilarious, these lovely mismatched ladies form the perfect circle of friends.

            [imagen] => http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/722/the-golden-girls
            [busquedaobtenidade] => tv maze
        )

)
```